# Unordered words matching in LIKE clause T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-matching

since I can not comment this post: [MySql: unordered words matching in like clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063704/mysql-unordered-words-matching-in-like-clause)

because of my low stackoverflow Reputation Points, and "answer" clearly says not to ask for clarification, help etc. I have to open up my own question.

The Situation:

I´m using T-SQL, I´ve made a Stored Procedure with a View as Table, within this table is a column which contains data of 3 fields (surname+givenname+id) as searchColumn.
My C# Application is passing a searchString into my stored procedure, the string always starts with % and all spaces get replaced by %.
The result should be geting all rows where searchColumn contains the input of searchString.
So when the search string is %mai%han%19% 
It should give me all People where surname contains mai, givenname contains han and id contains 19.
Well, this is working fine so far.
The Problem is, when the searchString contains %19%han%mai% it does not work anymore because it`s not the right order.

The Question:
So the question is (like the link i´ve postet)
unordered words matching in like clause? 
But different to the link, the solution should be in T-SQL.

Does anybody has a clue how to do this?

Thank you in advance
Sabrina

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another Solution to exactly meet the Goal:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DATABASE]
    @searchfield NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN 
declare @sql varchar(2000)
declare @search varchar(500), @count int, @part varchar(500), @rest varchar(500)

set @count = 0

set @search = @searchfield  

set @part = (substring(@search,0,@count))

set @rest = (substring(@search,@count+1,len(@search)))

set @sql = 'select * from [dbo].[DATABASE]'

set @count = charindex('%', @search)

set @part = (substring(@search,0,@count))

set @rest = (substring(@search,@count+1,len(@search)))

set @sql = @sql + ' where searchString like ''%'+ @part +'%'''

if(@count > 1 AND @count != 1)
BEGIN 
    WHILE (@count != 0)
    BEGIN       
        set @count = CHARINDEX('%', @rest)
        set @part = (SUBSTRING(@rest, 0, @count))       
        set @rest = (SUBSTRING(@rest, @count+1, len(@rest)))
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND searchString like ''%' + @part + '%'''
    END
END
SET NOCOUNT ON;
EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Hope that might help someone else too :)
One of my colleagues helped me, so thanks to him.